# separate number range from a file using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file with 5 columns and I want to separate the columns using number range as a criteria: example:

```
chr1    2120987 2144159     NM_001282670    0.48106
chr1    2123333 2126214     NM_001256946    2.71647
chr1    4715104 4837854     NM_001042478    0
chr1    4715104 4843851     NM_018836   0
chr1    3728644 3773797     NM_014704   4.61425
chr1    3773830 3801993     NM_004402   4.39674
chr1    3773830 3801993     NM_001282669    0
chr1    6245079 6259679     NM_000983   75.1769
chr1    6304251 6305638     NM_001024598    0
chr1    6307405 6321035     NM_207370   0.273874
chr1    6161846 6240194     NM_015557   0.0149477
chr1    6266188 6281359     NM_207396   0
chr1    6281252 6296044     NM_012405   14.0752
```

I want to remove 0 from the list , then would like to sort out numbers between 0.01 and 0.27 and so on....
I am new to shell programming....can someone help with awk ?
Thanks.

Comment: It really isn't clear what column you're interested in. From the mention of "0", I suspect the last. It is also not clear what you mean by "sort out", if all you want is to have the file sorted by the last number, `sort` is a much better alternative than `awk`.

Comment: When you say `sort out` do you mean `select` or something else? wrt `0.01 and 0.27 and so on` what does `and so on` mean? Are we supposed to be able to identify some sequence from those 2 numbers? Edit your question to show the expected output given that input. Also show what you have attempted yourself so far.

Answer (score 0):

As you are new to shell programming, you may not be aware of `grep` and `sort` which would be simpler for this job.

If you are hell-bent on `awk` as your tool of choice, please just disregard my answer.

I would do it like this:

```
grep -v '\s0$' file | sort -k 5,5 -g

chr1    6161846 6240194     NM_015557   0.0149477
chr1    6307405 6321035     NM_207370   0.273874
chr1    2120987 2144159     NM_001282670    0.48106
chr1    2123333 2126214     NM_001256946    2.71647
chr1    3773830 3801993     NM_004402   4.39674
chr1    3728644 3773797     NM_014704   4.61425
chr1    6281252 6296044     NM_012405   14.0752
chr1    6245079 6259679     NM_000983   75.1769
```

The `grep` with `-v` inverts the search and looks for lines not containing the sequence `space` followed by a zero followed by end of line. The `sort` sorts the data on column 5, and does a general numeric sort because of the `-g`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to select the rows in which $5 is non-zero and within a certain range, then indeed awk makes sense, and the following may be close to what you're after:

```
awk -v min=0.01 -v max=0.27 '
  $5 == 0 { next }
  min <= $5 && $5 <= max { print }'
```

Here, the call to awk has been parameterized to suggest how these few lines can be adapted for more general usage.